# Use of \@next doesn't match its definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, compilation-error

I get the error:

```
Use of \@next doesn't match its definition
```

With the following TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (10,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at (A).5(B);
  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(A).0.5(B) is wrong syntax. You perhaps mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (10,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]